# Rails: Querying a field that contains array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Created a table `clients` using Postgres database having an `order_ids` field which is an array field (`array: true`). I want to fetch only those clients whose `order_ids` field contains value '220'.

Example:
`order_ids` contains `["12","13","220"]`. So, in where clause I want to do something like this:

```
Client.where("order_ids contains(?)",220)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Client.where("220 = ANY(order_ids)")
```

More usage examples in [Rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try like this :

```
Client.where("? = ANY(order_ids)", 220)
```

Or

```
Client.where("order_ids @> ?", '{202}')
```

or

```
Client.where("? = ANY(order_ids)", '{220}')
```

You can find details [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/228-PostgreSQL-Array-The-ANY-and-Contains-trick.html) and [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/).

Comment: What is the purpose of enclosing `220` in braces? i.e '{220}'

Comment: First link I added in my answer having same syntax and seems like preferred one but you can also use it without braces. Works same.

Comment: Actually I got error when trying with braces, works fine without it

Comment: I haven't tested it with array of integer, It was working with string before. This might be issue of postgres version. I will look into it.